# Convert MM/DD/YYYY to the format YYYYMMDD (javascript)

Tags: javascript, date

I've been looking at many similar questions here, but the truth is I haven't been very successful, until I came across an answer that pleases me, but only almost does the trick:

```
 function convertDate (userDate) {
  // convert parameter to a date
  var returnDate = new Date(userDate);

  // get the day, month and year
  var y = returnDate.getFullYear();
  var m = returnDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = returnDate.getDay();

  // converting the integer values we got above to strings
  y = y.toString();
  m = m.toString();
  d = d.toString();

  // making days or months always 2 digits
  if (m.length === 1) {
    m = '0' + m;
  }
  if (d.length === 1) {
    d = '0' + d;
  }

  // Combine the 3 strings together
  returnDate = y + m + d;

  return returnDate;
}
```

It might be obvious, but the month and day in the output don't work 100% and I just don't know enough to understand why.

Output examples:

```
convertDate("12/31/2014");
"20141203"
convertDate("02/31/2014");
"20140301"
```

EDIT:
Replacing `getDay` for `getDate` seems to do the trick.

This answer works fine for my case too:

```
function convertDate (userDate) {
    return userDate.substr(6,4) + userDate.substr(3,2) + userDate.substr(0,2);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use momentjs?

Comment: use `var d = returnDate.getDate();` instead of `var d = returnDate.getDay();`

Comment: @Rajesh What alternative can I use then?

Comment: You are using an ambiguous date format. What should `convertDate("04/03/2014")` return? Instead, you should use `.split("/")` and built a `new Date(y,m,d)`... but then again, why bother with Date objects at all? Just... `function convertDate(userDate) {var parts = userDate.split("/"); return parts[2]+parts[0]+parts[1];}`

Comment: @Rajesh look at line `m = m.toString();` after `var m = returnDate.getMonth() + 1;`

Comment: Don't use the built-in parser at all, just reformat the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because [`getDay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) returns a week day 0 to 6.  You should use [`getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) instead.

Your second example is also a wrong date because February never have 31 days.

Perhaps you should try giving [momentjs] a shot. It really facilitate working with dates and transforming between formats using `format`.

Comment: You mean only get rid of the `getDay` and keep the others? Because doing that I still get this: `convertDate("02/31/2014");
"20140303"`

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. Replace it with getDate instead. Also note that ("02/31/2014") is a wrong date. February will never be 31 day

Comment: ow, you're right, I had not realized that! Seems like it's working fine

Comment: This is why you should use a library to handle dates. Handling dates manually is a pain in the a$$

Comment: I can see that, but this is a very small use case that doesn't justify the use of a library imo, but I'll keep that in mind for the future

Comment: You're correct. If you are sure about that and you have absolute control over the dates that will be coming to you then it makes no sense using a whole library to do a simple task.

Comment: Agreed, thank you for the help and suggestions, it was very helpful!

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it is sorted

Answer (score 2):

Your code won't work properly even if you replace function getDay for getDate because you are using invalid date format.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Fall-back_to_implementation-specific_date_formats

Generally if you need to handle only this one date format and it will not be changed in the future than your function can be as simple as:

```
function convertDate (userDate) {
    return userDate.substr(6,4) + userDate.substr(3,2) + userDate.substr(0,2);
}
```

Comment: Hum, I see, but it won't be a problem anyway.
And like you said, I only need to handle this specific format, so your answer is quite simple and works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code `var d = returnDate.getDay();` to `var d = returnDate.getDate();`

```
function convertDate (userDate) {
  // convert parameter to a date
  var returnDate = new Date(userDate);

  // get the day, month and year
  var y = returnDate.getFullYear();
  var m = returnDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var d = returnDate.getDate();

  // converting the integer values we got above to strings
  y = y.toString();
  m = m.toString();
  d = d.toString();

  // making days or months always 2 digits
  if (m.length === 1) {
    m = '0' + m;
  }
  if (d.length === 1) {
    d = '0' + d;
  }

  // Combine the 3 strings together
  returnDate = y + m + d;

  return returnDate;
}
```